# Running into issues with django/vue (and possibly livereload)

Tags: django, vue.js, livereload

So I've got a Django/Vue project I'm trying to get off the ground. It's currently being pretty inconsistent. (I was able to get Vue to generate some things, but not others)

I first got Vue working, but upon realizing I would need to wipe browser history, I followed these instructions pretty much to the letter: https://github.com/tjwalch/django-livereload-server
Although it was unclear that one needed to spawn a new session and run both livereload and runserver concurrently, I eventually figured it out and got rid of the following warnings.

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:32657/livereload.js net::ERR_CONNECTIONREFUSED
```

But Vue is inconsistent. Something simple:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="app">
  <p>{{ title }}</p>
</div>

    <script>
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
      title: 'yadda yadda'   
  }
});
</body>
</html>
```

And nothing on the screen. I'm not entirely sure livereload is the issue.
[image: screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delimiters!

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
  data: {
      title: 'yadda yadda'   
  }
```

Apparently I had previously set them and stopped for whatever reason. (hence the inconsistency)